# Why does Prison Architect work in the gnome DE but not in DWM?

Tags: gnome, arch-linux, steam, dwm

I have a laptop running Arch Linux and primarily use dwm as the window manager. The first time I played Prison Architect (a game on steam) for the first time, it ran fine. After a later reboot I wanted to play it again, but this time, it crashed immediately every time it opened. I tried all sorts of methods to get it to work, before finally installing gnome-shell and playing Prison Architect in that. It worked, and I have no idea why. After that, it still didn't run in dwm. Why, and how can I fix this?

Comment: When you run through the terminal, what output do you get?